# Method mapping not using an interface method

Tags: android, xml

How does Android's View Objects call a method inside my activity? For example, when you generate a view (like a button) dynamically, you have to add an click listener and then your activity will implement click listener and then the button object will have a reference to your activity through the interface.

My question though is when you create buttons in the XML file, you can specify an attribute "onClick" and then give a custom method name such as `public void button1pushed(View v)` how does the button object reference my activity if my activity doesn't implement anything?

Comment: If you Activity doesn't implement it, it will likely crash. Have you tested it.

Comment: it can be done by [reflections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)